# How to call a method from WindowsForms in Monogame?

Tags: winforms, methods, monogame

Hi im currently working on a project. My main form is a form and whenever i click on a button the monogame program starts. This works.

Now i made a method in the main form and i want to pass the bool to the monogame form.

Main Form method: (if checkbox is checked monogame should draw a skyline)

```
public bool skyCheck()
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            sky = true;                
        }
        else
        {
            sky = false;
        }
        return sky;
```

Monogame check:

```
if (skyCheck() == true)
        {
            DrawSky();
        }
```

This gives me the name 'skyCheck' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: The code you have posted has nothing to do with your problem. It sounds like you are declaring skyCheck() in a different class to where you are trying to use it. You'll need to supply more information you want someone to help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

I made a Control that embeds a monogame into a form so that a seperate program doesn't have to be run. It isn't the normal embedded monogame you see that only gives you a graphics device and no update or game methods. it's an actual monogame embeded.

This is not the source of your problem but it could help fix it along with make your program better.

[Here](http://cracked-ice.com/Downloads/StackExchange/MonoGameControl.zip) is the source and some brief documentation is contained in the Readme on how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Pass a reference of the form to the constructor of Game1:

```
public class Game1 : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    //Change the Form1 to the name of the form class.
    Form1 form;

//...

    public Game1(Form1 form)
    {
       this.form = form;
       graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
       Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }
//...
// I will assume the DrawSky() should be called in Draw.

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
//...
       if (form.skyCheck()) // the "== true" is redundant.
       {
           DrawSky();
       }
//...
    }
}
```

The following code would normally be in `Program.cs`, but as a Window Forms application, this code would be in the form that launches the game:

```
game = new Game1(this); // where "this" refers to the current form
game.Run();
```

Please note the caveats to mixing Windows forms and MonoGame:

1. The form's message pump and the Game run in the same thread. Any stall on the form will cause the game to lag.
2. There will be a performance penalty.
3. Make sure the game shuts down properly before the form is unloaded to ensure the resources are cleaned up properly.

---

It is is possible to start another thread for the game to run in(thus bypassing the first two caveats), but, all communication between the two threads must be thread safe. Thread safety is guaranteed for a Boolean assignments, as well as Integer assignments (=< 32 bits for 32 bit processes, and =< 64 for 64-bit processes).

Exit coordination in both threads is required.